# Node.js not rendering html page from 'public/views' route

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I am trying to render some html, after executing a xml http request from index.html, but the server is not rendering my html page, even if the log seems to work just fine:

```
<input type="button" id="response_2" value="No, let me create one :0" class="button" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" onclick="createAccount()">
```

This is the button found in the index.html

```
function createAccount()     {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "/createAccount");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This is the javascript function. also found in the index.html file, which is executed when pressoing the 'response_2' button

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http');
    var port = 3000;
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    httpServer.listen(5500);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log("someone here...");
        res.render('index.html');
    });

    app.get('/createAccount', function (req, res) {
        console.log("here!");
        res.render('createAccount.html');
    });

    app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        res.render('login.html');
    });

    app.get('/forgotCredentials', function (req, res) {
        res.render('forgotCredentials.html');
    });
```

This is the configuration of the node.js server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
app.get('/createAccount', function (req, res) {
  console.log("here!");
  res.render('createAccount.html');
});
```

makes it so that when someone visits the `/createAccount` URL in their browser they'll see the page you've told the server to return. Your `createAccount()` function does not open this URL in the browser, it only makes the request to render that page, so the server returns the page but you never actually visit it.

Why don't you just use

```
<a href='/createAccount'>
  <button>No, let me create one :0</button>
</a>
```

in your page instead of that input element?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are missing a bit of code.
In your client example you have the `createAccount` function which fires a `XMLHTTPRequest` to the server.

```
function createAccount() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "/createAccount");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

But it then misses the part what it should do with the `response` of the request. Add a `onreadystatechange` method to the `xhttp` instance like you see here below.

```
function createAccount() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "/createAccount");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The `onreadystatechange` will be called whenever the `readyState` of the request has changed. As described [here on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange). From within the function you can control what has to be done with the result.

As far as I can tell from your code the `console.log(xhttp.responseText);` should output the `createAccount.html` page as a string.

My guess is that you should simply navigate to the `/createAccount` by using the `href` of a link.

```
<a href="/createAccount" title="Create account">Create account</a>
```